# How to prevent jquery terminal from replacing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I'm using jquery terminal (http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) to emulate a console in JavaScript. When I type `&para=` (e.g. as part of a URL) in the prompt, it gets automatically replaced by `¶=`. This also happens if I call `echo` from a function.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question makes perfect sense.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I would imagine it's because this problem appears to exist within the code of the 3rd party website. It's not something anyone here will be able to help you with. The best thing you can do is to contact the support service of that website and let them know of the issue.

Comment: For those who don't get it, `&para;` is the HTML entity for  ¶. It might be your browser, have you tried in different ones?

Comment: As a workaround you can try and use `&amppara`. The problem seems to be with the plugin though in that it appends the text as html instead of plain text.

Comment: I am aware, that `&para` is HTML-related. Also, it happens in every browser (which is totally logical), but ONLY if you type `=` after it. It is not a problem to echo `&params{'test': 42}` but if you add `=` at the end of the string, it gets replaced.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior in chromium, if I echo or change prompt I've got &para not character. Can you create jsfiddle demo?

Comment: @jcubic on your [demo page](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/#demo) in the JavaScript Interpreter demo, I can reproduce the issue in Chrome 40 and IE11. Note, that you have to echo/type `=` after `&para`

Comment: I get this behavior only when I echo with raw option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the issue by replacing `&` with `&amp;`. I realize, that this is just a workaround, but it suffices for my cause.